# How to force subtitles in VLC to display at bottom

Tags: 12.04, vlc

I need some help in forcing subtitles to be displayed at the bottom(to be exact, in those black bars). I've tried the tools->preferences and then subtitles option-> I've tried by giving 150px, but subtitles are still being displayed on the image(movie). Could anyone help me in doing this?

Comment: If Rick's answer below doesn't fix it, it may be that the subtitles are '[burned-in](http://www.google.com/search?&q=subtitles+burned+in)', or part of the image.

Comment: Read here: [VLC: How to show subtitles under the video](http://askubuntu.com/a/304043/35512)

Comment: @TomBrossman - that is not the reason why this doesn't work. also, the below answer is not the way for what is asked: subtitles **below** the image ("in those black bars"). That is, the question asks for the subtitles to appear below the image and in the black area below **when there is such a black area there**: at a certain aspect ratio. the answer below keeps the subtitles above that black area.

Comment: this was asked also  [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/237174/47206) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/526286/47206) - namely because the proposed solution does not work

Comment: see my comment above with the linked questions and my unswers thereunder. are you asking to move subtitles under the video in all cases, even when (depending on aspect ratio) there are **no black bars**? - or just **as low as possible**? please consider editing your question to clarify.

Comment: @cipricus This question has been closed for nearly two years, with OP last seen about six months ago. It's probably best to ask a new question which focuses on your slightly different point, which will have much better odds of getting a good answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 7):

Click "Tools" on VLC's main menu bar. Click "Preferences" on the drop-down menu.

Click the "Subtitles & OSD" icon in the left-hand pane of the Preferences window.

Enter a value into the "Force subtitle position" text box at the bottom of the "Subtitles & On Screen Display Settings" window. A positive value moves the subtitles upward on the screen; a negative value lowers the subtitles.

Read more: How to Change the Position of Subtitles in VLC | [eHow.com](http://www.ehow.com/how_8452353_change-position-subtitles-vlc.html#ixzz2HG7A8nNL)

also see this [how-toforce-subtitles](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-change-vlc-subtitles-settings/)

Comment: this moves subtitles as low as possible **within** the image frame. that may be as low as possible when the image is filling the entire screen depending on the aspect ratio: that is, when there are no "black bars" as the question puts it. but the question explicitly asks for subtitles on the black bars: that is, under the image when there is space under it

Comment: As per comment to OP, see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/526286/position-subtitles-as-low-as-possible-in-vlc). Since this question is closed, can't add this as an answer, but here's the tl;dr: in vlc preferences, show "all", under video/filters, enable checkbox "Video cropping filter" (don't forget!), then edit video/filters/Cropadd Padd "pixels to padd to bottom" to "100"; and "Save".  Then edit "simple" preferences, Subtitles/OSD, "Force subtitle position", -200 px, "Save". Restart VLC. See also: https://www.vlchelp.com/how-to-change-subtitle-position-in-vlc/